# How to prove that a subspace of vectors (functions) is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

In an assignment we were given was the task to prove that a vector space consisting of continuous functions $f$ is infinitely dimensional. The functions have to be (continuous) and must have the value $0$ outside of $[-1, 1]$. In [-1,1], they can have any value. The way I chose to tackle the problem is by defining a subspace of $V$, lets call it $Q$ which consists of infinitely linearly independent functions $f_n$, then i would be able to argue that $Q$ is infinitely dimensional and therefore $V$ is also infinitely dimensional. The idea was to construct such a set of functions $Q$ as:
[image: the set Q]

which would consist of continuous functions which reaches the requirements. The problem i stumbled upon is actually proving that this set of functions (subspace) is linearly independent. By definition, I want to prove that:
$$
a_1 f_1(x) + a_2 f_2(x) + ... + a_n f_n(x) = 0
$$
This equation is only true if all scalars $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ are equal to zero. But it turns out it is harder than I expected and I'm feeling like i squeezed myself in a hard problem to prove using the basic linear algebra knowledge we were given. I idealy don't want to use the properties of the sinus functions being orthogonal or using integrals to prove their linear independency because we have not gone through that topic. I have tried setting $x$ to a value which would give a nice pattern (such $x=\frac{1}{2}$) but that's where i got stuck. When $x=\frac{1}{2}$ you'd get that for each $n$ that's an even number, $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) = 0$, and for odd $n$, you either get $-1$ or $1$. But this doesn't take me anywhere because $Q$ is supposed to consist of infinitely many $f_n$:s. I can argue that for each odd $k_x$ we would need to have an opposite sign $k_y$ so that $k_x - k_y = 0$  but with $Q$ being infinitely large, i could as likely have infinitely many $k_x$-$k_y$ pairs that make the linear-dependence equation hold true without all scalars being zero.

Any advice on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Differentiate the linear dependence equation several times to get a Vandermonde determinant

Comment: IIRC linear independence in infinite dimensional vector spaces only means that equation has to hold for any finite index set $\{k_1,k_2,…,k_n\}\subset \Bbb N$. So you won’t have infinitely many pairs of whatever.

Comment: You can use the fact that the functions $\sin(\pi n x), \sin (\pi m x )$ are orthogonal if $m\neq n$, and in particular, none of them can be a non-zero  linear combination of the others.

Comment: The elements of a subspace are NEVER linearly independent. $Q$ is not a subspace of $V$. You probably meant "subset" instead of "subspace"

Answer (score 0):

If $[a,b]$ is as closed interval $a,b\in \mathbb R$, $a\leq b$, then write $\mathcal C[a,b]$ for the space of real-valued continuous functions on $[a,b]$, and let
$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal C_0[a,b] &= \{f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: f \text{ continuous and } \forall x, f(x)=0 \text{ if } x\notin [a,b]\}\\
&\cong \{f\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R: f \text{ continuous and } f(a)=f(b)=0\}
\end{split}
$$
Here the isomorphism at the start of the second line is given by restricting the domain of $f$ from $\mathbb R$ to $[a,b]$, and its inverse by simply extending the domain of a function $g\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ to all of $\mathbb R$ by setting $g(x)=0$ if $x \notin [a,b]$ (this gives a continuous extension of $g$ precisely when $g(a)=g(b)=0$).

You are asked to show that the space $\mathcal C_0[-1,1]$ is infinite dimensional. As the OP suggests, to show this it suffices to find an infinite linearly independent set in $\mathcal C_0[-1,1]$. This is possible to do in many ways, but I would like to point out that some of the specific details of the definition of the space $\mathcal C_0[-1,1]$ are irrelevant to the essence of the question.

**Claim 1**: if $a_0<b_0$ and $a_1<b_1$ then $\mathcal C[a_0,b_0] \cong \mathcal C[a_1,b_1]$, that is, the spaces of continuous functions on any two closed intervals of positive length are isomorphic. Moreover, there exist isomorphisms which restrict to give an isomorphism between $\mathcal C_0[a_0,b_0]$ and $\mathcal C_0[a_1,b_1]$.

*Proof*: It suffices to assume that $a_0=0,b_0=1$. But then if $\phi\colon [a_1,b_1] \to [0,1]$ is given by $\phi(t) = \frac{t-a_1}{b_1-a_1}$, it follows that $\phi^*\colon \mathcal C[0,1] \to \mathcal C[a_1,b_1]$ given by
$\phi^*(f) = f\circ \phi$ gives a linear map which has inverse $\psi^*$ where $\psi=\phi^{-1}\colon [0,1]\to [a_1,b_1]$ is given by $\psi(t) = a_1+t(b_1-a_1)$. The final sentence follows immediately once one notices that $\phi^*(f)(a)= f(0)$ and $\phi^*(f)(b)=f(1)$.

[*Here we only need $\mathcal C[a_0,b_0]$ and $\mathcal C[a_1,b_1]$ to be isomorphic as vector spaces, but $\phi^*$ is in fact an isomorphism of rings -- it is compatible with addition and multiplication of functions.*]

**Claim 2**: $\dim(\mathcal C_0[-1,1]) = \dim(\mathcal C[-1,1])$.

*Proof*: Since $\mathcal C_0[-1,1]$ is a subspace of $\mathcal C[-1,1]$ it is clear that $\dim(\mathcal C_0[-1,1]) \leq \dim(\mathcal C[-1,1])$. Thus to complete the proof, by Claim 1 it suffices to show that $\mathcal C[-1,1]$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathcal C_0[a,b]$ for some $a<b$. To see this, let $\tau\colon \mathcal C[-1,1]\to \mathcal C_0[-2,2]$ be the map given by
$$
\tau(f)(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}f(t), & \text{ if } |t|\leq 1, \\
(2-|t|)f(\frac{t}{|t|}), & \text{ if } 1\leq |t|\leq 2.\end{array} \right.
$$
Thus $\tau(f)_{|[-1,1]} = f$ and, for $\epsilon \in \{\pm 1\}$, $\tau(f)$ linearly interpolates between $f(\epsilon)$ and $0$ between $[\epsilon ,2\epsilon]$. Thus $\mathcal C[-1,1]$ is a subspace of $\mathcal C_0[-2,2]$ so that $\dim(\mathcal C[-1,1])\leq \dim(\mathcal C_0[-2,2]) = \dim(\mathcal C_0[-1,1])$ (where the equality follows from Claim 2).

Thus $\mathcal C_0[-1,1]$ is infinite-dimensional if and only if $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is infinite-dimensional. But if $\mathcal I = \{f_n(t) = t^n\}$ then $\mathcal I$ is infinite and linearly independent, since any linear combination of the $f_n$s gives a polynomial function $p(t)$. But if $N$ is the maximum among the integers $n$ such that $f_n$ has a nonzero coefficient in $p(t)$, then $p$ has at most $n$ roots, and hence it cannot be identically zero on the infinite set $[0,1]$.